# Error using "if" in R: "== : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Tags: r, for-loop, spatial-analysis, if-statement, rstudio

I am using *st_covered_by* function (from *sf* package) with a *for* loop and *if* statement to create a dummy variable to know if specific points from different municipalities are found inside the polygon of their corresponding municipality.

The code used is the one below:

```
for (k in 1:nrow(PointLocationVar)){
   if(st_covered_by(PointLocationVar[k], municipality[municipality$municipality.name==PointLocationVar[k]$Municipality, ])[k]>0)
      PointLocationVar$Valid[k] <- as.integer(1)
}
```

I get the following error:
*Error in if(st_covered_by(PointLocationVar[k], municipality[municipality$municipality.name==  :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed*

Is there any way to solve this error? I am having trouble and getting stuck in this part.

Comment: Would you mind making your example fully reproducible?

Comment: Check that everything in `municipality$municipality.name==PointLocationVar[k]$Municipality` is as expected - something in that expression is causing a missing value instead of a TRUE/FALSE and that's causing the error. Try printing out the various bits of it before that line. Or it could be something else. Impossible to tell without a reproducible example or some summary values.